# Error in permforming ListKeys() operation on AWS KMS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kms

I am using `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` to initialise an `AWSKMSClient` in my android application to get the temporary credentials for authorizing encrypt() operation and ListKeys() of the AWS KMS service. In my IAM role policy, I have specified the authorization to encrypt operation on a specific KeyID and ListKeys operation on all resources. Still I am getting an Access Denied Exception with the error that

```
assumed-role/Cognito_usernameUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized
to perform the operation ListKeys on resource *. 
(Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID 123456788)
```

I have run simulation on IAM role Cognito_usernameUnAuthRole and that says that ListKeys operation is allowed.
I am unable to understand why is this happening ? Here is the IAM Policy attached to my role.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:ListKeys",
            "kms:ListAliases",
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "apigateway:POST",
            "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kms:Encrypt",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:region:1234:key/123456789”
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the IAM policies attached to `Cognito_usernameUnauth_Role`?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the description.@jellycsc